# how to disable scrollbars of textarea in javaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a TextArea and I want to disable the scrollbars, I was able to disable the horizontal scrollbar using:

```
    TextArea.setWrapText(true);
```

But I am unable to disable the vertical scrollbar all I can do is hide it, I want the TextArea to be with 22 fixed rows and don't want to take any further input in the TextArea. If that can be done with CSS is also fine, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove Horizontal Scrollbar

```
textArea.setWrapText(true);
```

Remove Vertical Scrollbar

```
ScrollBar scrollBarv = (ScrollBar)ta.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
scrollBarv.setDisable(true);
```

CSS

```
.text-area .scroll-bar:vertical:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Where to add the remove vertical scrollbar code section?

Comment: (ScrollBar)ta.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical"); does not work with a TextArea as of at least JavaFX 8. I'm not sure if it ever worked. This answer is incorrect.